# Call completionHandler in function after embedded function returns value? Swift

Tags: swift, function, completionhandler

What is the proper way to call a completionHandler() in a function that contains another function? Basically, I want to wait until the embedded function is done before calling the completionHandler.

```
func somefunc {    

transferManager?.download(downloadRequest).continue( {(task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject! in

    // Your handler code here
    if (task.error != nil) {
        print("- Error while downloading!")
        print(task.error)
    }

    else if (task.result != nil) {
        //let downloadOutput: AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput = task.result as! AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput
        do {
            let dFile  = try NSString(contentsOf: downloadingFileURL as URL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print(dFile)
            modelsParseCSV(contentsOfURL: downloadingFileURL)
        }
        catch {
            print("- Error: Unable to retrieve contents of csv file")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("- Uknown error: AWSS3 get file")
    }


    print("------------ AWS Get Models File End ----------")
    return nil

})

completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: Would moving `completionHandler()` to the line above `return nil` do the trick?

Comment: Even better - replace the call to `return nil` with the call to `completionHandler()`. But where is `completionHandler` defined?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code- completion handler is defined up above, I just failed to copy it in. I'm seeing that if I call completionHandler before return nil, return nil is not called. It throws an error if I remove the return statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem. The following code calls the completion handler and after the embedded function is complete:

```
func AWS_getModelsFile(AWSMake: String, completionHandler: (() -> Void)! ) {

    .........

    transferManager?.download(downloadRequest).continue( {(task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject! in

        // Your handler code here
        if (task.error != nil) {
            print("- Error while downloading!")
            print(task.error)
        }

        else if (task.result != nil) {
            //let downloadOutput: AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput = task.result as! AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput
            do {
                let dFile  = try NSString(contentsOf: downloadingFileURL as URL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                print(dFile)
                modelsParseCSV(contentsOfURL: downloadingFileURL)
            }
            catch {
                print("- Error: Unable to retrieve contents of csv file")
            }
        }
        else {
            print("- Uknown error: AWSS3 get file")
        }


        print("------------ AWS Get Models File End ----------")
        completionHandler()
        return nil

    })
}
```